# CodeIgniter Anonymous Form Validation

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a code like this given below:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules("codetype", "Code Type", array(
        "codecheck" => function ($str) {
            // just return it false.
            return false;
        }
    ), array("codecheck"=>"return this message"));
```

I want it to return the codecheck error message. but codeigniter form validation class returns this message:

> "Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name
>   Code Type".

How can I write a fully anonymous CodeIgniter function with an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

You can remove `required` if you want and also set your `if` condition

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('codetype', 'Code Type',
       array(
          'required',
          array(
                'codecheck_callable',
                function($str)
                {
                  // Check validity of $str and return TRUE or FALSE
                  if ($str == 'test') 
                  {
                     $this->form_validation->set_message('codecheck_callable', 'can not be test');
                     return false;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                      return TRUE;
                   }
               }
          )
     )
);
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods

Comment: maybe codeigniter form validation custom error message don't work directly on the set_rules function if the validation is anonymous. i mean on the third parameter of set_rules. but this works. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to CodeIgniter docs at https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html

you can do it like this

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'The {field} field can not be the word "test"');
```

Comment: sorry but this also don't work with an anonymous function. and also I wanted a fully anonymous one. It's available also in codeigniter docs but it won't work

Comment: Then try changing the last param from 
`array("codecheck"=>"return this message")` to `array("codetype"=>"return this message")`